# VS 2015 - Designer randomly loses bindings

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

We use VS 2015 community edition.

I have a user control with multiple binding sources on that are bound to our business objects :

Library > Namespace > Class > Item

For some unknown reason and this has happened a handful of times without warning or any errors on save/build, the binding sources data source will change to :

Library > Namespace > Class

which is missing the final part.

All the controls keep their bindings to the properties it's just the binding sources data source that changes. This gives a run time error of 'Cannot bind to the property 'X' on the binding source.'

It doesn't specify a control or name.

Has anyone ever experienced this or know what might be causing it?

Thanks

Comment: can you show what's inside the class?

Comment: We use the CSLA.net framework. it's just a standard business base class, it has properties, a fetch method etc. do you need to see an example?

Comment: base on experience, I just rewrite the properties of my classes into something like, public string someVariable {get;set;}, and if you have an interface, make sure to use all the methods inside it to the class it's inherited